# List not stored in Database - Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I try to store a PersonManager and its List into a Database.

Actually everything seem to work smooth, no errors and the PersonManager is properly stored in the Database. But not its List

But as soon as I access the database and try to iterate over the Persons saved in the List of PersonManager the returned List is always empty.

I work with Spring-Boot, Hibernate and have a H2-Filebased DB. The log is at the end of this post and important to see what is going on.

Here [my Repo](https://github.com/realsony/h2TestEnv)

**Person**

```
   @Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    final String name;
    @ManyToOne
    private PersonManager personManager;

    public PersonManager getPersonManager() {
        return personManager;
    }

    public void setPersonManager(PersonManager personManager) {
        this.personManager = personManager;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Long getId() {

        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (!id.equals(person.id)) return false;
        return name != null ? name.equals(person.name) : person.name == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**PersonManager**

```
   @Entity
public class PersonManager {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personManager", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private final List<Person> personList = new LinkedList<>();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        PersonManager that = (PersonManager) o;

        if (!id.equals(that.id)) return false;
        return personList != null ? personList.equals(that.personList) : that.personList == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + (personList != null ? personList.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Person> getPersonList() {
        return personList;
    }

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        personList.add(person);
    }

    public void removePerson(Person person) {
        personList.remove(person);
    }
}
```

**HibernateApplication**

```
   @SpringBootApplication
public class HibernateApplication {


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HibernateApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateApplication.class);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner addObservables(ObserveableRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {
            useObserver(repository);

            // fetch all customers
            log.info("PersonManager found with findAll():");
            log.info("-------------------------------");
            for (PersonManager personManager : repository.findAll()) {
                log.info("ListContent: " + personManager.getPersonList().size());
            }
            log.info("");

        };
    }

    private void usePersonManager(PersonManagerRepo repository) {
        PersonManager personManager = new PersonManager();
        personManager.addPerson(new Person("Hans"));
        personManager.addPerson(new Person("Peter"));
        personManager.addPerson(new Person("Max"));
        log.info("List.size() : " + personManager.getPersonList().size());
        repository.save(personManager);
    }


    /**
     * Start internal H2 server so we can query the DB from IDE
     *
     * @return H2 Server instance
     * @throws SQLException
     */
     /*
    @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
    public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
        return Server.createTcpServer("-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9092");
    }
    */
}
```

**PersonManagerRepo**

```
public interface PersonManagerRepo extends CrudRepository<PersonManager, Long> {

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I logged the size and the elements of the list as you can the below. While first runtime the elements are present. After re-establishing they are gone.

```
2017-06-12 17:12:26.160  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-12 17:12:26.185  INFO 3252 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4516af24: startup date [Mon Jun 12 17:12:26 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-12 17:12:26.948  INFO 3252 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b98d9ce8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-06-12 17:12:27.156  INFO 3252 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-12 17:12:27.162  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2017-06-12 17:12:27.163  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.14
2017-06-12 17:12:27.212  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-06-12 17:12:27.212  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1029 ms
2017-06-12 17:12:27.284  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-06-12 17:12:27.286  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 17:12:27.287  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 17:12:27.287  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 17:12:27.287  INFO 3252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-06-12 17:12:27.506  INFO 3252 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-12 17:12:27.513  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-06-12 17:12:27.546  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-06-12 17:12:27.546  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-06-12 17:12:27.547  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-06-12 17:12:27.567  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-06-12 17:12:27.619  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-06-12 17:12:27.858  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: com.example.hibernate.Person (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2017-06-12 17:12:27.901  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table person if exists
Hibernate: drop table person_manager if exists
Hibernate: create table person (id bigint generated by default as identity, name varchar(255), person_manager_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table person_manager (id bigint generated by default as identity, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table person add constraint FKmyv6vk7htrqtbt7ji7rngwgh2 foreign key (person_manager_id) references person
2017-06-12 17:12:27.912  INFO 3252 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
2017-06-12 17:12:27.928  INFO 3252 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-06-12 17:12:28.173  INFO 3252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@4516af24: startup date [Mon Jun 12 17:12:26 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-12 17:12:28.208  INFO 3252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-06-12 17:12:28.209  INFO 3252 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-06-12 17:12:28.223  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-12 17:12:28.223  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-12 17:12:28.241  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-06-12 17:12:28.369  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-06-12 17:12:28.398  INFO 3252 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-06-12 17:12:28.400  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : List.size() : 3
Hibernate: insert into person_manager (id) values (null)
2017-06-12 17:12:28.434  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : Observables found with findAll():
2017-06-12 17:12:28.434  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : -------------------------------
2017-06-12 17:12:28.446  INFO 3252 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select personmana0_.id as id1_1_ from person_manager personmana0_
Hibernate: select personlist0_.person_manager_id as person_m3_0_0_, personlist0_.id as id1_0_0_, personlist0_.id as id1_0_1_, personlist0_.name as name2_0_1_, personlist0_.person_manager_id as person_m3_0_1_ from person personlist0_ where personlist0_.person_manager_id=?
2017-06-12 17:12:28.493  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : ListContent: 0
2017-06-12 17:12:28.493  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : 
2017-06-12 17:12:28.494  INFO 3252 --- [           main] c.e.hibernate.HibernateApplication       : Started HibernateApplication in 2.47 seconds (JVM running for 2.718)
```

Can you please tell me how to fix that issue?

Thank you :)

Comment: when you start application do you see that hibernate do any ddl in log file ? like create / drop ?

Comment: you are right it only inserts but it doesn't create a table (i just read the console output i copied here) why is that? Since I don't get any error message I don't know how to fix that behavior

Comment: Check that file exists

Comment: spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2.  If it doent check config and check that config is accepted by spring hibernate config

Comment: yes file is/was there.

Comment: i updated my question with the log of your suggestion to change update to create in the properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that you are setting up a bidirectional relationship and you want to cascade the operations.  So the first change is to add a cascade to your @OneToMany annotation on the PersonManager entity.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "personManager", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Then you need to keep in mind that when you are creating new Child elements you need to associate them to their parent.

In order to do this first add a new constructor to the Person entity:

```
public Person(String name, PersonManager personManager) {
    this.name = name;
    this.personManager = personManager;
}
```

Note you may also want to add the default public constructor so Hibernate doesn't need to use an interceptor.  If you watch the logs closely you are probably seeing a warning from your logs with your current implementation.

```
public Person() {
    this.name = null;
}
```

Lastly change your HibernateApplication class.  As you are creating your Person objects call the new constructor and pass in the instance of the Parent.  Your other option would be to create each of the Person objects and then call the setPersonManager method passing in the PersonManager instance for each.

```
    private void useObserver(ObserveableRepository repository) {
    PersonManager personManager = new PersonManager();
    personManager.addPerson(new Person("Hans", personManager));
    personManager.addPerson(new Person("Peter", personManager));
    personManager.addPerson(new Person("Max", personManager));
    log.info("List.size() : " + personManager.getPersonList().size());
    repository.save(personManager);
}
```